# Using argparse scripts along with larger project

Tags: python-3.x, argparse, program-entry-point

My objective is to use argparse command-line script along with a larger project. Especially I want to use some models from my project inside argparse_command.py.

Let's say the project structure is as follows:

```
myproject/
├── app
│   ├── db.py
│   └── __init__.py
│── management
│    └── argaparse_command.py
└── main.py
```

And the body of argparse_command.py:

```
import argparse
from app.db import engine

print('Print this when run from command-line.')
```

When I run the code from the command-line I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "argaparse_command.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.db import engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

And the problem is to import some stuff from within my project.
I have two questions:

1. Is it possible at all, and if so, how to do it?
2. What is the difference between running *main.py* with some IDE (pycharm) and *argaparse_command.py* with command-line (why it behaves differnt).

Answer (score 1):

To be able to import `app`, you'd either have to install `app` as a python package (using a `setup.py` to specify how to install it for example), or be in the `myproject` working directory so your python interpreter has direct access to `app` in its path. So to answer question 1, yes it's possible.

The difference between running `main.py` with an IDE vs running on the command line is going to be the working directory the script is run in, which python executable is used and which virtual environment (if any) is used, and what flags are passed. You can check your IDE settings on how it invokes a script, and basically replicate that on the command line if you want.

Comment: It is as you said, placing the file next to main.py did the job. So partially succeed.